# kubectl exec: $PATH: unknown command terminated with exit code 126

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

Trying to exec into a container with the following command

`kubectl exec -it my-pod my-container1 -- bash`

Gives error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "my-container1": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> command terminated with exit code 126

The pod *my-pod* has two containers. And *my-container1* has alipne image with bash installed.
Trying to get shell into the container, it is not able to find bash.

Kubectl client version: v1.17.0

Answer (score 2):

Adding -c before the container name worked.

`kubectl exec -it my-pod -c my-container1 -- bash`